# Count number of documents in an ElasticSearch snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I count the number of documents that are in a snapshot without restoring it?

I looked at the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/get-snapshot-api.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/get-snapshot-status-api.html), but they give me the number of shards and sizes, but not the number of documents.

Comment: Hi perhaps do a search that returns all documents, or this might help https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27502

Comment: @ironman in ElasticSearch it's not possible to do a search on a snapshot. The snapshot needs to be restored before you can do searches in it. But restoration is a process that can take hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the last [Elastic{ON} Global](https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/global) event (Oct 13-15, 2020), Steve Kearns mentioned in the Elastic Stack keynote that a new feature called "searchable snapshots" ([see PR #50239](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/50239/)) was going to be released in an upcoming version (a beta version will be released in 7.10).

[image: searchable snapshots]

Cold and Frozen searchable snapshots were also further explained in two talks by Jason Tedor:

- "Cost-effective data storage with data tiers"
- "How we built this: Data tiering, searchable snapshots, and asynchronous search"

[image: cold searchable snapshots]
[image: frozen searchable snapshots]

**UPDATE**:

7.10 got released on Nov 11th, 2020, and [searchable snapshots](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/searchable-snapshots.html) are now available in beta.

Comment: For your information, 7.10 has just got released minutes ago and searchable snapshots are available in beta: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/searchable-snapshots.html